# Слово закон в предложении

Tags: прописная-строчная

В данном тексте слово закон пишется с большой или маленькой буквы?
*"12 декабря мы отмечаем День Конституции России - знаменательную дату, которая занимает особое место в исторической летописи нашего государства. В 1993 году россияне всеобщим голосованием поддержали основной ***закон*** своей страны. "*

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что   "основной закон"  нужно ВСЕГДА писать со строчной буквы, так как это словосочетание не является именем собственным. В частности, предложения "Конституцию называют Основным законом страны", "Конституция - Основной закон государства" мне не кажутся верными. Официальное название - это "Конституция Российской Федерации", также используется "Конституция" как сокращенный вариант.